# How to do Oauth Authentication using seperate new tab for verification of account?

Tags: twitter, basic-authentication

What is the Authentication Strategy for opening new (tab) Window for Oauth Authentication and returning to previous tab (logged In) upon successful authentication?

I am using passportjs authentication strategies for Twitter, Facebook and Google. But all of that does authentication in the same window-tab. Is there a predefined strategy which I can follow to do the above?

I can open the permission window in new account using a(target="_blank"), but it does not return to previous tab upon account authentication (by user).

Edit (based on following answer)

Login Page looks like:-

```
!!!
html
head
    script.(type='text/javascript')
        function newWindow (auth_target) {
            authWindow = window.open(auth_target);
            var authenticationSuccessUrl = "/home"
            authWindow.onClose = function () {
                alert('onClose called.');
                authWindow.close();
                window.location = authenticationSuccessUrl;
            }
        }


    body
        button(type="button", onclick="newWindow('auth/google');").btnLogin with Gmail
```

For New Window (home) i wrote:-

```
!!!
html
head
    script(type='text/javascript').
        function onAuthSuccess() {

            authWindow=window.location;
            window.onClose();
        }

body(onload='onAuthSuccess();')
```

Its not a full code i was suppose to write, but even this does not work. If the Home page is called after an intermediate authentication window (by google, for password entry) the above code does not work, and window does not close.

// just as some more information, ignore if not necessary
Also please note, that,

```
    window.close()
```

works only if the parent window that triggered it open is open. If the current window is a standalone the above window.close() will not close the window. Likewise, the above Home page code fails to close current window.

Comment: There is an example for popups [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/issues/188#issuecomment-266909361). If you want to use a new-tab rather than a popup, I think you just replace `name = 'facebook_login'` with `name = '_blank'`, and omit the `specs` argument. (and maybe remove the `display: 'popup'` line in server code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I see the code can be changed as: This would just create one popup window and it will get closed after authentication.

You have Login page code as :

```
!!!
html
head
    script.(type='text/javascript')
        function newWindow (auth_target) {
            authWindow = window.open(auth_target);
            authWindow.onClose = function (authenticationSuccessUrl) {
                alert('onClose called.');
                authWindow.close();
                window.location = authenticationSuccessUrl;
            }
        }


    body
        button(type="button", onclick="newWindow('auth/google');").btnLogin with Gmail
```

The newWindow('auth/google') should have the following code.

```
!!!
html
head
    script(type='text/javascript').
        function onAuthSuccess(authSuccessUrl) {    
            window.onClose(authSuccessUrl);
        }
        function ajaxPost() {            
        var uname = $("#name");
        var pass = $("#password");
             $.ajax({
                  url: "/auth/google/",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: {username : uname, password: pass}                      
                }).success(function(data){
                    var redirectUrl = data.url; // or "/home" as you had mentioned
                    onAuthSuccess(redirectUrl);
                });
        }

body
   p UserName:
    input#name(type="text", name="username")
p Password:
    input#password(type="text", name="password")
p: button(type="submit", onclick="ajaxPost()").btnLogin
```

If you can post through ajax to the google authentication service and get the the success response you can use this method.

Hope this works out well for you.

Answer (score 3):

When creating the new window for authentication you can get the reference to the window object.

```
var authWindow = window.open("location","");
```

In the authentication tab you on authentication success you can call a method which would close the window and set a property or call a method on the source window suggesting that authentication is complete.

```
var authenticationSuccessUrl = "http://auth-sucess.url"
authWindow.onClose = function () {
    authWindow.close();
    window.location = authenticationSuccessUrl;
}
```

On the authentication window javascript:

```
var onAuthSuccess = function (){
    window.onClose();
}
```

Be sure to remove the reference to the authWindow at the end of processing. Having window objects as references could potentially lead to memory leaks in the application.

Comment: How do i implement it? I will need some handholding. I am using node.

Comment: Lets say you have a link "Login", on the page "Index", which opens up a new window to authenticate. In this page "Index" you would have to bind a javascript click event to the "Login" button.

The click event handler would have the first two blocks of code in the answer.

The new window that opens now will have the third block of code.

The a(target="_blank") is the "Login" link I'm assuming.

Comment: The above works when the New Window that opens contains the 3rd block of code. But when i call for authentication url/auth/google (for example) and the user is not signed in. And i redirect, after user input, to a success.url page which now contains the third block of code. The system fails to execute the onClose() function of block 2. I presume this happens because the authWindow variable does not associate with success.url but with the interim /auth/google page which then redirects to success.url. Hence making system unresponsive.

Comment: There are two ways you can go about this. First thing that strikes is if you do the auth with google as a ajax post rather than a redirect and on success call the third block of code, it should work fine.
My guess for why this didnt work with the redirect is cause the page reloaded with different javascript. Ideally the window object should still contain the onClose method. I maybe wrong here.

Comment: Another way would be to have the first "Index" page check periodically with a server url with the session id. And in the auth page you can store the session id mapped to authentication success or failure at the server side. Then on getting an auth success in the "Index" page you can close the authWindow. This however is very round about and involves frequent network requests at regular intervals, its quite non-performant. I could probably look at why it failed if you added some code here.